# What's the input_size in a BasicRNNCell in tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

According to the documentation of `BasicRNNCell`:

```
__call__(
    inputs,
    state,
    scope=None)

Args:
inputs: 2-D tensor with shape [batch_size x input_size].
```

It seems that `input_size` can be different at different runs? As far as I know about RNN, the `input_size` determines the internal weight matrix W_x with shape `(input_size, hidden_state_size)`, and it should be consistent. What if I run this cell with `input_size=3` and `input_size=4` alternately?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47965256/internal-variables-in-basicrnncell/47986005#47986005 You might understand after this post!

Answer (score 0):

`inputs` is a 2-D tensor: `[batch_size x input_size]`.

You are right, the `input_size` must correspond to the `num_units` of the RNN cell. But `batch_size` can vary and only has to correspond to the `state`, the other parameter of the call.

Try this code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn import BasicRNNCell

dim = 10
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, dim])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[4, dim])
z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, dim + 1])
print('x, y, z:', x.shape, y.shape, z.shape)

cell = BasicRNNCell(dim)
state1 = cell.zero_state(batch_size=4, dtype=tf.float32)
state2 = cell.zero_state(batch_size=8, dtype=tf.float32)

out1, out2 = cell(x, state1)
print(out1.shape, out2.shape)

out1, out2 = cell(x, state2)
print(out1.shape, out2.shape)

out1, out2 = cell(y, state1)
print(out1.shape, out2.shape)
```

Here's the output:

```
x, y, z: (?, 10) (4, 10) (?, 11)
(4, 10) (4, 10)
(8, 10) (8, 10)
(4, 10) (4, 10)
```

This cell accepts `x` with both states, `y` with `state1` and doesn't accept `z` with any state. Both of the following calls result in error:

```py
out1, out2 = cell(y, state2)     # ERROR: dimensions mismatch
print(out1.shape, out2.shape)

out1, out2 = cell(z, state1)     # ERROR: dimensions mismatch
print(out1.shape, out2.shape)
```