# internal variables in BasicRNNCell

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following example code to test `BasicRNNCell`. I'd like to get its internal matrix so that I can calculate the values of `output_res`, `newstate_res` using my own code to make sure that I can reproduce the values of `output_res`, `newstate_res`.

In tensorflow source code, it says `output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)`. Does anybody know how I can get `W` and `U`? (I tried to access `cell._kernel`, but it is not available.)

```
$ cat ./main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# vim: set noexpandtab tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=-1 fileencoding=utf-8:

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 4
vector_size = 3

inputs = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32
        , [batch_size, vector_size]
        )

num_units = 2
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, num_units], tf.float32)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=num_units)
output, newstate = cell(inputs = inputs, state = state)

X = np.zeros([batch_size, vector_size])
#X = np.ones([batch_size, vector_size])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    output_res, newstate_res = sess.run([output, newstate], feed_dict = {inputs: X})
    print(output_res)
    print(newstate_res)
sess.close()

$ ./main.py
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
```

Comment: You might be looking for the [``cell.variables`` property](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicRNNCell#variables). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640455/tensorboard-visualize-weights-of-lstm/47643427#47643427) answer might be useful. If that's not what you're looking for, could you link the source code? Or explain what ``W`` and ``U`` are?

Comment: See the source code here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L343

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: You recognize you're after `cell._kernel`. Here's some code to get kernel (and bias) using the `variables` property, which is in most TensorFlow RNNs:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

batch_size = 4
vector_size = 3
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, vector_size])

num_units = 2
state = tf.zeros([batch_size, num_units], tf.float32)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicRNNCell(num_units=num_units)
output, newstate = cell(inputs=inputs, state=state)

print("Output of cell.variables is a list of Tensors:")
print(cell.variables)
kernel, bias = cell.variables

X = np.zeros([batch_size, vector_size])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    output_, newstate_, k_, b_ = sess.run(
        [output, newstate, kernel, bias], feed_dict = {inputs: X})
    print("Output:")
    print(output_)
    print("New State == Output:")
    print(newstate_)
    print("\nKernel:")
    print(k_)
    print("\nBias:")
    print(b_)
```

That outputs

```
Output of cell.variables is a list of Tensors:
[<tf.Variable 'basic_rnn_cell/kernel:0' shape=(5, 2) dtype=float32_ref>, 
<tf.Variable 'basic_rnn_cell/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32_ref>]
Output:
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]
New State == Output:
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.]]

Kernel:
[[ 0.41417515 -0.64997244]
 [-0.40868729 -0.90995187]
 [ 0.62134564 -0.88962835]
 [-0.35878009 -0.25680023]
 [ 0.35606658 -0.83596271]]

Bias:
[ 0.  0.]
```

Long answer: You also ask about how to get W and U. Let me copy the implementation of `call` and discuss where W and U are.

```
def call(self, inputs, state):
     """Most basic RNN: output = new_state = act(W * input + U * state + B)."""

    gate_inputs = math_ops.matmul(
        array_ops.concat([inputs, state], 1), self._kernel)
    gate_inputs = nn_ops.bias_add(gate_inputs, self._bias)
    output = self._activation(gate_inputs)
    return output, output
```

Doesn't *look like* there's a W and a U, but they are there. Essentially, the first `vector_size` rows of the kernel are W and the next `num_units` rows of the kernel are U. Maybe it's helpful to see the element-wise math in LaTeX:

[image: w and u inside k]

I'm using *m* to be a generic batch index, *v* as `vector_size`, *n* as `num_units`, and *b* as `batch_size`. Also *[ ; ]* denotes concatenation. Since TensorFlow is batch-major, implementations usually use right-multiply matrices.

And since this is a very basic RNN, `output == new_state`. The "history" for the next iteration is simply the output of the current iteration.

Comment: Useless `sess.close()`?